# Get SharePoint view results on form library (not list) in Azure Logic Apps

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, azure-logic-apps

Is it possible to retrieve the results of a view on a SharePoint form library using Azure Logic Apps. From what I can tell you can retrieve the view results for a SharePoint list. You can also get a list of file properties for a form library. You could then loop through all those files, read them, and then pull the data from those files in a loop. But it does not seem that you can create a view on a form library then reference that view using an Azure Logic App. It only appears that you can do that for SharePoint lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since logic app doesn't provide a connector which can do this job, I think it can't be implemented in logic app. You can create a post on [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps) page to suggest azure develop team to add this feature.